# editing span innerHtml with timer

Tags: javascript, settimeout, innerhtml

I need to update my span with a string and a countdown from 5 to 1

HTML:

```
                <div id="timerB" class="timerB"/>
                    <span id="span"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="controls">
                <button type='button' id="b1" onclick="pressBut(this)">Part1</button>
```

JS:

```
 var time=6;
 var elem1=document.getElementById('span');
 function startTimer() {

           time=time-1;
           setTimeout(startTimer,1000);
           console.log(time);
       }



        function pressBut(button) {
            if(button.id=='b1'){
                startTimer();
                timerId=setTimeout(function(){
                    vid.currentTime=wave;
                },5000);
                elem1.innerHTML='start in ' + time + ' seconds';
            }
```

The console returns that var time changes as expected,but span on screen doesn't.

Comment: Remove forward slash from `<div id="timerB" class="timerB"/>`

Comment: didn't make any diffrence

Comment: Of course `console.log(time);` does its work in `startTimer`. But why should it also update any DOM content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute `pressBut`, it starts the timer and changes the content of `span`. In `startTimer`, you only update the variable `time`, without updating the `span`. So you have to add the code to update the content of `span`.

```
function startTimer() {
    time=time-1;
    elem1.innerHTML='start in ' + time + ' seconds'; //Update span inner HTML
    setTimeout(startTimer,1000);
    console.log(time);
}
```

Comment: It worked,although had to change time=time-0.5; so it work properly.When I have it -1 it removes 2 seconds.Whats up with that?

Comment: You sure the button is not pressed twice? or are there any other functions that are changing the value of `time`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this line of code:

```
elem1.innerHTML='start in ' + time + ' seconds';
```

like so

```js
var time=6;
var elem1=document.getElementById('span');
function startTimer() {
           time=time-1;
           setTimeout(startTimer,1000);
           console.log(time);
           elem1.innerHTML='start in ' + time + ' seconds';
 }

 function pressBut(button) {
     if(button.id=='b1'){
          startTimer();
          timerId=setTimeout(function(){
            //vid.currentTime=wave;
          },5000);
     }
 }
```

```html
<div id="timerB" class="timerB">
     <span id="span"></span>
</div>
<div id="controls">
     <button type='button' id="b1" onclick="pressBut(this)">Part1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked,although had to change time=time-0.5; so it work properly.When I have it -1 it removes 2 seconds.Whats up with that?